# multiple words replace in txt file using java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I need to replace multiple words in txt file using java. This program only replacing the only one word, in whole file.

```
import java.io.*;

public class MultiReplace
{
 public static void main(String args[])
     {
     try
         {
         File file = new File("file.txt");
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
         String line = "", oldtext = "";
         while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
             {
             oldtext += line + "\r\n";
         }
         reader.close();
         String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll("india", "freedom");       
         FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("file.txt");
         writer.write(newtext);writer.close();
     }
     catch (IOException ioe)
         {
         ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: can you show the content of `file.txt`

Comment: yes set of words i need to replace with another for example ( india as freedom   )  (bird as peacock ) like this

Comment: hi afzalex , that txt file nothing for sample i took ..basically i need to replace many set of word in one instance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   import java.io.*;

    public class MultiReplace
{
 public static void main(String args[])
     {
     try
         {
         File file = new File("file.txt");
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
         String line = "", oldtext = "";
         while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
             {
             // Replace in the line and append
              line = line.replaceAll("india", "freedom");
             oldtext += line + "\r\n";
         }
         reader.close();    
         FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("file.txt");
         writer.write(newtext);
         writer.flush();
         writer.close();
     }
     catch (IOException ioe)
         {
         ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
```

Refer [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to understand why your version is not working.

Comment: this is working for one set of word but i have many set of words to repalce for example (india as freedom) (bird as peacock )

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct!! I ran your program as is and it is able to replace all the india with freedom in the text file